# Error with procmail script to use Maildir format

Tags: linux, email, procmail, maildir

I have this code in /etc/procmailrc:

```
DROPPRIVS=yes

DEFAULT=$HOME/Maildir/

:0
* ? /usr/bin/test -d $DEFAULT || /bin/mkdir $DEFAULT
{ }
:0 E
{
        # Bail out if directory could not be created
        EXITCODE=127
        HOST=bail.out
}

MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir/
```

But, when the directory already exists, sometimes it will send a return email with this error: `554 5.3.0 unknown mailer error 127`. The email still gets delivered, mind you, but it sends back an error code to the sending user as well.

I fixed this temporarily by commenting out the `EXITCODE` and `HOST` lines, but I'd like to know if there is a better solution.

I found this block of code in multiple places across the net, but couldn't really find why this error was coming back to me. It seems to happen when I send an email to a local user. Sometimes the user has a `.forward` file to send it on to other users, sometimes not, but the result has been the same. I also tried removing `DROPPRIVS`, just in case it was messing up the forwarding, but it did not seem to affect it.

- Is the line starting with `* ? /usr/bin/test` a problem?
- The `*` signifies a regex, but the `?` makes it return an integer value, correct?
- What is the integer being matched against? Or is it just comparing the integer return value?
- Do I need a space between the two blocks?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the [dovecot instructions for procmail](http://wiki.dovecot.org/procmail) is what I was looking for.

```
# file: /etc/procmailrc
# system-wide settings for procmail
SHELL="/bin/bash"
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t"
LOGFILE="/var/log/procmail.log"
DROPPRIVS="yes"
DELIVER="/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver"
# fallback:
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir/"
MAILDIR="$HOME/Maildir/"
:0 w
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
| $DELIVER -m spam
:0 w
| $DELIVER
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet on some kind of race condition.  Does it matter if you wrap up the /usr/bin/test line into a little shell script? like:

```
* ? /usr/local/bin/make-sure-exists-dir $DEFAULT
```

with a make-sure-exists-dir that does:

```
/usr/bin/test -d "$1" || mkdir "$1"
```

also, in looking at the manpage for mkdir, -p doesn't error on existence, so you could just do:

```
* ? mkdir -p $DEFAULT
```

Comment: Good thinking, but it's been a while, so I'll need to put this back on my todo list. If I get a chance to try it out, I will accept it if your answer comes back to be right.